# Display Dynamic Checkbox in <rich:datatable and based on user selection rendered TextArea for current Object

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Hi I am attaching my code, My problem i si am getting a list from the database and i am dispalying on the UI in a datatable with only checkbox.

Once user will select any of the check box then i need to renderedd on text area for that checkbox. So checkbox and textarea will be dynamic.

I have written some code in bean also but that is not working for first object it is working fine but for remaining object it is not workinhg please help to resolve problem

Bean Code:

```
public void addSharedMessage()
{   
    for(DocumentTypeDTO documentTypeDTO1 : shareGovtAgencyList)
{
    System.out.println(documentTypeDTO1.getSelected());
    if( documentTypeDTO1.getSelected())
        {
        this.setSharedMessageRendered(true);
        setSharedMessageRendered(true);             
    } else {
        this.setSharedMessageRendered(false);
    }
}
}
```

XHTML code:

```
<rich:dataTable width="100%" id="searchResult" border="0" rowKeyVar="
    value="#{myBean.sharedList}" var="item"
    headerClass="head" cellpadding="2" 
    rowClasses="odd,even" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <rich:column  style="text-align:center; background-color:#FFFFFF" width="1%">
     <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="khudh" value="#{item.selected}" immediate="true" >
         <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{myeBean.addSharedMessage}"                              reRender="committeemenbersname" />
         </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>                            
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column  style="background-color:#FFFFFF" id="committeemenbersname" >
     <h:outputText value="#{item.documentName}" />
     <rich:separator lineType="none" />
         <h:inputTextarea id="shareProfileComment" rows="2" cols="45"  
              rendered="#{myBean.isSharedMessageRendered}"  >
             <f:validateLength maximum="200" />
         </h:inputTextarea> 
    </rich:column>
 </rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: are you trying to show the textarea only once or multiple checkbox selection?

Comment: Thanks for your response. for every selection i need to display checkboc to put some comment. last 5 days i am stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate all the values every time. you did any one value is true, and all the remaining should be false. I think this is the problem.

Try this,

```
public String addSharedMessageAction()
    {
        DocumentTypeDTO documentTypeDTO1 = shareGovtAgencyList.get(dataTableIndex);
        System.out.println(documentTypeDTO1.getSelected());
        if (documentTypeDTO1.isSelected())
        {
            documentTypeDTO1.setSharedMessageRendered(true);
        }
        else
        {
            documentTypeDTO1.setSharedMessageRendered(false);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

XHTML code:

```
   <rich:dataTable id="dataTableID"
                 value="#{Sample.sampleList}"
                 rendered="#{Sample.sampleDataTableRendered}"
                 var="sampleBean"
                 width="600"
                 rowKeyVar="currentIndex">

                 <f:facet name="header">
                   <rich:columnGroup>
                       <rich:column>
                           <h:outputText value="select"/>
                       </rich:column>

                       <rich:column>
                           <h:outputText value="Comment"/>
                       </rich:column>
                    </rich:columnGroup>
                 </f:facet>

                 <rich:column >
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkboxId" 
                         value="#{sampleBean.selected}">
                         <a4j:support action="#{Sample.addSharedMessageAction}"
                              event="onclick" reRender="dataTableID">
                                <a4j:actionparam name="actionParemId"
                                       value="#{currentIndex}"
                                       assignTo="#{Sample.dataTableIndex}"/>
                         </a4j:support>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column >
                     <h:inputTextarea value="#{sampleBean.comment}"
                                rendered="#{sampleBean.isSharedMessageRendered}"/>
                </rich:column>

        </rich:dataTable>
```